# Cursor resets itself at beginning of textarea on input

Tags: android, html, web, textarea

I have a basic textarea looking like this:

```
  <textarea class="text-input__input"
        name="message"
        placeholder="{{'incidents.input_placeholder' | translate}}"
        rows="1"
        minHeight="21"
        required
        #textInput
        [(ngModel)]="message">
  </textarea>
```

used for a website. When typing in this textarea on an Android device using Chrome on landscape mode the cursor is reset at the start of the input at every character typed. Thus if we type "hello" this comes out as "olleh". This behavior is observed only on Android devices and only on Google Chrome, it works fine on Firefox. The textarea behaves normally on emulator and on iOs devices.
I tried to switch off autocorect but it didn't help.

Any idea where this might come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it appears that the textarea has a really weird behavior when it's container reaches a height of 0px. I'm not quite sure where this might come from but adding `min-height: 1px` to the container of my textarea fixed the issue.